# UPSERT function in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, upsert

I have a Google sheets file stored in a PostgreSQL database table, and need to update this table anytime a change is made to the google sheet. Each day, a script runs which generates a list of dictionaries for each row in the sheet, as follows:

```
content = [{'Date': 01-01-2018, 'Day_Name': 'Monday', 'Message': NULL, 'More_Info': 'this is more info'},
           {'Date': 02-01-2018, 'Day_Name': NULL, 'Message': NULL, 'More_Info': NULL},
           {'Date': 03-01-2018, 'Day_Name': NULL, 'Message': NULL, 'More_Info': NULL},
           {'Date': 04-01-2018, 'Day_Name': NULL, 'Message': NULL, 'More_Info': NULL},
           ......
           {'Date': 10-09-2018, 'Day_Name': 'Tuesday', 'Message': 'Hello', 'More_Info': NULL}]
```

I've written the below UPSERT query which achieves what I want:

```
cur.executemany(""" 
      INSERT INTO table
      (hol_date, day_name, message, more_info)
      VALUES 
      (to_date(%(Date)s, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), %(Day_Name)s, %(Message)s, %(More_info)s)

      ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT holiday_date_and_day_name
      DO UPDATE SET
      message = %(Message)s, 
      more_info = %(More_info)s 
      """, content)
```

However, after adding details to a row which previously had the date only, the ID for that row will change to the latest serial ID (i.e. if there are 200 rows in the sheet, the row with ID 2 will change to 201 after adding a Day_name)

My table is created as follows:

```
cur.execute(""" CREATE TABLE table (
            hol_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            hol_date DATE NOT NULL,
            day_name CHARACTER VARYING (250),
            message TEXT,
            more_info TEXT """

cur.execute(""" ALTER TABLE public_holidays ADD CONSTRAINT holiday_date_and_day UNIQUE (hol_date, day_name) """
```

Comment: The query can't detect information on rows deleted from the sheet. You'd have to make a second query where you present a sequence of all unique `(hol_date, day_name)` tuples of the data present in the sheet and delete all rows that are not in that sequence.

Comment: Thankyou, that clears up one issue.

Comment: `UPSERT` relies on a unique constraint (primary key or otherwise). If you are inserting data that is *not* violating the unique constraints, then there is no way to know that `(date, NULL)` should be replaced with `(date, day)`, so a *new row* is insert (and with a new row comes a new id). You need to pick a different conflict criteria in that case.

Comment: If you are seeing big jumps in a serial primary key, that means that the intervening numbers have been used in previous transactions, that may or may not have been rolled back. This is normal behaviour and has nothing to do with your UPSERT here, really.

Comment: See [postgres 9.0.4 sequence skipping numbers](//stackoverflow.com/q/21356375) for that part.

Comment: Thankyou for the help, could you clarify what you would suggest in terms of choosing different conflict criteria? What would you do in this situation?

Comment: I'd look for an index setup that would only accept `(dateN, NULL)` *or* `(dateN, *)` tuples for a given `dateN`; so only a single `(dateN, NULL)` row is tolerated, *or* multiple `(dateN, dayname)` rows, but never both.